# How to jquery .load only a specific section of a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, wordpress

This code pulls in the next page of posts on my wordpress site. It targets a specific part of the page, the div `<div id="blog-grid">` and only pulls that section into my page. It looks good on the front end, however, when I inspect the response it gets on the console, it's responding with the full page and not just "blog-grid". This makes the page slower and loads unnecessary content. How can I modify this code to request or to get a response with only the specific part of the page (`<div id="blog-grid">`)? I'm a beginner in ajax and have been breaking my head for the last few hours over this.

```
jQuery(function(){
    var page = 2;
    var loadmore = 'on';
    jQuery(document).on('scroll resize', function() {
      if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() + jQuery(window).height() + 700 > jQuery(document).height()) {
        if (loadmore === 'on') {
          loadmore = 'off';
          jQuery('#spinner').css('visibility', 'visible');
          jQuery('#lazyload').append(jQuery('<div class="blog-grid" id="p' + page + '">').load(global.getPermalink + "page/" + page + ' #grid-item', function() {
            page++;
            loadmore = 'on';
            jQuery('#spinner').css('visibility', 'hidden');
          }));
        }
      }
    });
    jQuery( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, options ) {
        if ( $(".blog-grid").is(':empty'))
        {
           loadmore = 'off';
           $(".all-posts-message").fadeIn(600);
           setTimeout(function(){
               $(".all-posts-message").fadeOut(600);
               }, 5000);
        }
      if (xhr.responseText.indexOf('class="blog-grid"') === -1) {
      }

      //blog grid
    var small_blocks2 = $('.blog-grid > div:nth-child(5n+3), .blog-grid > div:nth-child(5n+4), .blog-grid > div:nth-child(5n+5)').not(".block-1, .block-2"); 
    $(small_blocks2).addClass("col-xs-4 block-sm");

    });
}); //blog grid add classes after new content is inserted
    var block_1 = $(".grid-item").eq(0)
        $(block_1).addClass("col-xs-8 block-lg block-1");
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any way to do that. Ajax will just request the full resource at any url you give it. Put simply, jQuery.load () can only retrieve the same resources you can manually browse to.

So unless you code a page server-side that will only deliver the specific div you want (e.g. by using a query string) you'll always be retrieving the full page, then filtering that result client-side.